# Decoding Morse Code to Text

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

When I try to replace the the inputed morse code into text I get a problem. Basically the problem is that when the user inputs the ".", the prorgram prints the letter "E"(which is "." in morse code) and ignores all of the other periods after it to make other letters with two or more consecutive periods.

How should I solve this?

I know that this is probably a very newbie question but I've been struggling all day to find an answer for this.

Here's the code

```
public partial class Morsetext : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public string[] aakkoset = { ".", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                                 "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
                                 "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
                                 "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", 
                                 "U", "V","W", "X", "Y", 
                                 "Z", "Ä", "Ö", "0", "1", 
                                 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
                                 "7", "8", "9", "?", ":",
                                 ",", "@", "/", "=", " ",
                                 };
    public string[] morse = {".-.-.-", ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", 
                              "..-.", "--.", ".... ", "..", ".---", 
                              "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", 
                              ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", 
                              "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", 
                              "--..", ".-.-", "---.", "-----", ".----", 
                              "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", 
                              "--...", "---..","----.", "..--..", "---...",
                              "-....-", ".--.-.", "-..-.", "-...-", " ", 
                              };

    public Morsetext()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bShort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        char piste = '.';

        tBoxMorse2.Text += piste.ToString();

    }

    private void tBoxMorse2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        tBlockText2.Text =  tBoxMorse2.Text.ToUpper()
            .Replace(morse[0],aakkoset[0])
            .Replace(morse[1],aakkoset[1])
            .Replace(morse[2],aakkoset[2])
            .Replace(morse[3],aakkoset[3])
            .Replace(morse[4],aakkoset[4])
            .Replace(morse[5],aakkoset[5])
            .Replace(morse[6],aakkoset[6])
            .Replace(morse[7],aakkoset[7])
            .Replace(morse[8],aakkoset[8])
            .Replace(morse[9],aakkoset[9])
            .Replace(morse[10],aakkoset[10])
            .Replace(morse[11],aakkoset[11])
            .Replace(morse[12],aakkoset[12])
            .Replace(morse[13],aakkoset[13])
            .Replace(morse[14],aakkoset[14])
            .Replace(morse[15],aakkoset[15])
            .Replace(morse[16],aakkoset[16])
            .Replace(morse[17],aakkoset[17])
            .Replace(morse[18],aakkoset[18])
            .Replace(morse[19],aakkoset[19])
            .Replace(morse[20],aakkoset[20])
            .Replace(morse[21],aakkoset[21])
            .Replace(morse[22],aakkoset[22])
            .Replace(morse[23],aakkoset[23])
            .Replace(morse[24],aakkoset[24])
            .Replace(morse[25],aakkoset[25])
            .Replace(morse[26],aakkoset[26])
            .Replace(morse[27],aakkoset[27])
            .Replace(morse[28],aakkoset[28])
            .Replace(morse[29],aakkoset[29])
            .Replace(morse[30],aakkoset[30])
            .Replace(morse[31],aakkoset[31])
            .Replace(morse[32],aakkoset[32])
            .Replace(morse[33],aakkoset[33])
            .Replace(morse[34],aakkoset[34])
            .Replace(morse[35],aakkoset[35])
            .Replace(morse[36],aakkoset[36])
            .Replace(morse[37],aakkoset[37])
            .Replace(morse[38],aakkoset[38])
            .Replace(morse[39],aakkoset[39])
            .Replace(morse[40],aakkoset[40])
            .Replace(morse[41],aakkoset[41])
            .Replace(morse[42],aakkoset[42])
            .Replace(morse[43],aakkoset[43])
            .Replace(morse[44],aakkoset[44]);

    }
```

Comment: That "replace" statement makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: I'm sorry guys for the ugly syntax. I'm still learning this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to reorder your replaces from longest morse string first to shortest morse string last.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did this and now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

Morse code can be decoded using [dichotomic search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search). The decision tree [looks something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#Alternative_display_of_more_common_characters_in_International_Morse_code)

[image: Morse code]

Comment: Thank you parapura rajkumar! I followed this chart to solve the problem.